# Extracting clusters in from pheatmap in different order to distance

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I have created a heatmap in R using `pheatmap` as seen below. I would like to extract the clusters outlined in black, due to the patterns identified within. The problem I have is that the distances are not in the order I wish to extract the clusters. Is there a smart way I can do this whilst still keeping the information contained? I am using Ward D2 clustering method.

I have so far used:

```
df$clust <- cbind(df, cluster = cutree(pat$tree_col,  k = 4))
```

but of course this goes by distance. Thanks!

[image: heatmap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not obvious what you mean by *"the distances are not in the order I wish to extract the clusters"*: a "distance" is a matrix with pairwise distance values, which are symmetric. It is used to induce an ordering among the samples, via some method; the way you compute or use the distance defines the groups/ clusters.

In this case, `pheatmap`'s clusters are computed by `hc(.)` via some distance -- see `?pheatmap` to change the parameters -- and can be [accessed from the return object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820158/pheatmap-in-r-how-to-get-clusters?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), along with other information.

Did you annotate the figure yourself? It is not even clear if rows are clustered as well; please provide some complete example.

In my experience, however, R package `dynamicTreeCut` provides you with some interesting dendrogram cutting heuristics, which seem to make sense in many cases.

Paper: https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/24/5/719/200751

Package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dynamicTreeCut/index.html

Comment: This is more like a comment where you are asking questions of the OP to better clarify the question.